# How to Crystal Report 2010 application deployment with WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I’m created WPF C# (.Net 4.0) application using Crystal Report 2010. In here I’m integrate windows forms CrystalReportViewer to WPF window and also load a Dataset to CrystalReportViewer  as follows.

```
 ExtraCR report = new ExtraCR();//crystal report object
 report.SetDataSource(DataAss.extset);//dataset load to crystal reoprt
 CrystalReportViewer rptViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
 WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
 rptViewer.ReportSource = report;
 host.Child = rptViewer;
 CReport.Children.Add(host);
```

It is compile and run perfectly. When I deploy this project, and open Crystal Report it crashing. I haven’t pass experience about Crystal Report deployment. So how to give path and add Crystal Report when project deploy according to my code? Can anyone guide me to deploy Crystal Report project according to my code? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Does the computer you're deploying it to have the Crystal Reports re-distributable installed?  You can find it here: [Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010 Reference](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/crystalreports-dotnet?rid=/webcontent/uuid/d01fdad8-44e5-2d10-61ad-9d2d4158f3a8)